# Angular js $window.open not working in .success for mobile browser

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, jquery-mobile, window.open

I'm working with Angularjs and I got a problem. The function $window.open(/somewhere) works perfect on pc browsers and mobile browser. But there's 1 case it doesn't work. Please help to look below:

```
 $window.open("https://www.myurl.com");  // OUTSIDE OF REQUEST - no problems 

 $https({
    type: "GET",
    url: "backendURL",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        $window.open("https://www.myurl.com");  //This doesn't work. 
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        //alert(error);
    }
});
```

Note that this is just happen with mobile browser : chrome and safari (I didn't test for others) So I think maybe someone has experience with this. Please please please help and advise.

Thanks ...

Comment: What is with `$window`?? Pop Up blocker is probably blocking it.

Comment: hi bro, I already turn off the Pop up blocker :( still not work :(
as I said, out side the request, it works perfect :( but inside, can not :(

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue right now. I got this very same issue in $.ajax request in normal javascript and got it fixed, but for angular I don't how to fix it. Tried the same way I do to normal js, didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution online, hope it will help you. do `var win = window.open();` before the callback function, then inside `.success`, change url by doing `win.location = url;`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Yabin. This is a nice idea. I tried but doing win.location = url; doesn't work :(

Comment: It works for me, can you post the code which doesn't work? Maybe there's some syntax error.

Comment: In the demo, you are using ajax instead of http get. In ajax, there's a different way to solve this issue, I modified your javascript, please check here, it's working now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGrbjr

Comment: @LạiCôngThành have u checked it?

Comment: Hi Yabin. I checked.
it's awesomeee. Thank you so much ^____^

Answer (score 1):

I think the overarching problem has to do with the ["this" scope in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback). If you are able to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)from the ES6 version of JavaScript you can simply do

```
success: (msg)=>{
  $window.open("https://www.myurl.com");
}
```

I imagine most people will not have this option. In which case you can do something similar to what Yabin suggested:

```
//somewhere else in code.
var scopedWindow = $window;
//
success: function(msg){
  scopedWindow.open("https://www.myurl.com"); 
}
```